# Where is the manual for Visual Studio 2010 Professional Retail?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Where is the manual that used to come with Visual Studio 2008?

Did they stop including this in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I disagree with the downvote and VTC: the [FAQ] allows questions pertaining to *software tools commonly used by programmers*

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this isn't a question about the programmers tool; it's a question about the content of a retail purchase's box, and that is something that should be asked of the vendor themselves. (It's a vendor sales question, not a tool support question. "What comes in the retail box for VS2010 Pro? Does it have a printed manual?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2008 was the last VS version that included a pre-packaged version of the MSDN library.  In VS2010 and up you can use the Help Library Manager to download off-line content for the help viewer.  The MSDN article for it [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264831.aspx).